# Correct df in longitudinal linear mixed model?

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, degrees-of-freedom

I am having trouble understanding how to correctly apply a linear mixed model to my data to measure the effect of wifi exposure.

4 beehives contained sensors collecting data on temperature (DHT22_t, DHT11_t), humidity (DHT22_h, DHT11_h), decibels (db), and pressure (kPa).

2 hives were exposed to wifi for 2 15 day periods with about 15 days in between exposure.

Here is a sample of the data: (n=~4million, for model took a sample every 1hr and that n=3202)

```
time    dht22_t dht11_t dht22_h dht11_h db  pa  treatment_hive  wifi  hive_id
1   01/09/2014 15:19    NA      NA  NA      NA  51.75467    NA      0   1   1   
2   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  59.8    44  55.27682    100672  0   1   1
3   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  60.3    44  54.81995    100675  0   1   1
4   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  60.9    44  54.14134    100671  0   1   1
5   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  61.1    44  53.88574    100672  0   1   1
6   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  61.2    44  53.68800    100680  0   1   1
```

Running a linear mixed model for each of the environmental sensors returns weird df which makes me skeptical.

```
lme_kPa <- lme(kPa~wifi*treatment_hive, random=~1|hive_id/time, data = HivesT1h, na.action=na.exclude)
summary(lme_kPa)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
Data: HivesT1h 
       AIC      BIC   logLik
  6923.501 6966.008 -3454.75

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | hive_id
        (Intercept)
StdDev: 5.77681e-05

 Formula: ~1 | time %in% hive_id
    (Intercept)   Residual
StdDev:   0.7078384 0.01996731

Fixed effects: kPa ~ wifi * treatment_hive 
                        Value  Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)         100.55555 0.02816753 3203 3569.910  0.0000
wifi                  0.43529 0.03464226 3203   12.565  0.0000
treatment_hive        0.12763 0.04387843    2    2.909  0.1007
wifi:treatment_hive   0.09557 0.05374497 3203    1.778  0.0755

Correlation: 
                (Intr) wifi   trtmn_
wifi                -0.813              
treatment_hive      -0.642  0.522       
wifi:treatment_hive  0.524 -0.645 -0.816

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
    Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-0.06968701 -0.02122557  0.00429932  0.02350050  0.05588593 

Number of Observations: 3209
Number of Groups: 
      hive_id time %in% hive_id 
            4              3209
```

Why does the "treatment_hive" have 2 degrees of freedom while everything else has 3202 (the size of the data?) Shouldn't the df be 2 for everything?

What should be changed in the code to reflect this?

Thank you!